# Is there a way to build a command in a script and then execute it within the script with an alias?

Tags: linux, universe

I am creating a command in a variable then trying to assign the variable to an alias. If I do this at the command line, it works just fine, but when I put it in a script, it tells me command not found.

Here is the code I have in my script for building the command, setting the alias and then executing it:

```
fn_find_inode() {
    filename=$1
    cmd=""
    end_of_file=0
    while [[ $end_of_file == 0 ]]; do
        read -r line
        # the last exit status is the
        # flag of the end of file
        end_of_file=$?
        if [ $end_of_file != 1 ]; then
            #echo $line
            inodenum=$(ls -i $line | awk '{print $1}')
            #echo $inodenum
            cmd=$cmd" | grep -v $inodenum"
        fi
    done < $filename
                }
                
cmd1='list_readu EVERY DETAIL | grep " RU "'
fn_find_inode "/u2/eclipse/modules/ECL/scripts/other_scripts/exlrulocksfiles.txt"

cmd1=$cmd1$cmd' | sort -k2 -k7'
echo $cmd1
cd /u2/eclipse || exit 1
alias rulocks=$cmd1
alias rulocks > /tmp/rulocks.txt
source /tmp/rulocks
rulocks
```

This results in an error, command not found. If you source the file at the command line and the run rulocks you get no such error. I have tried to directly execute cmd1, but that results in an incorrect listing as the grep's are ignored and only the list_readu is executed.
Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

That's because aliases defined in *scripts* aren't persisted *outside* of it.

When you run this script:

```bash
alias helloworld="echo hello world"
```

in a shell, you can observe that `helloworld` can't be found.
However, when you source the file, it suddenly exists.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work, with or without aliases? I tried just running the cmd1 variable, but did not get the expected results. Am I fighting a losing battle?

Comment: maybe you can use bash's `exec` with the command to run as the argument

Comment: That just gives me the list_readu EVERY DETAIL section of the command and ignores all the grep's that follow.